# ¿Como usar o añadir dos componentes o más dentro de una seccion de un tab?

Tags: vue.js

Tengo este sistema de tabs,el cual me funciona perfectamente. Estoy aprendiendo VueJs. Tengo una inquietud con respecto a los componentes y/o templates. Mi inquietud es:

Poniendo como ejemplo cualquier ventana del tab,¿Como añado dos componentes dentro de un tab,me refiero a una de sus ventanas o secciones.

```js
const Home = {
  template: `
    <section class="content">This is the home screen.</section>
  ` };

const contentOne = {
  template: `<section class="content">Content One</section>` };

const contentTwo = {
  template: `<section class="content">


<div id="container11111111"></div>
 



  </section>` };

const contentThree = {
  template: `<section class="content">



  </section>` };

const contentFour = {
  template: `<section class="content">Content Four</section>` };

const contentFive = {
  template: `<section class="content">Content Five</section>` };


const Header = {
  template: `
    <section class="header">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="left">
          <h1 :style="titleStyles" :class="classList">{{title}}</h1>
          <p v-if="text">{{text}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div v-if="action"><button @click="doAction">Call {{action}}</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="top">
        <div class="left">
          <p>{{description}}</p>
          
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <p v-show="showMessage">You called method {{action}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
    </section>
  `,
  computed: {
    titleStyles() {
      return `color: ${this.color}`;
    },
    classList() {
      return this.customClasses.join(' ');
    } },

  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      // reset showmessage
      vm.showMessage = false;
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showMessage: false };

  },
  props: {
    color: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'orange' },

    customClasses: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: [] },

    title: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'YOU MUST PUT A TITLE HERE!!!' },

    text: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'Default Text' // this default will not work if 'config' object is passed to route. Even if it is empty.
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'Default description' },

    action: {
      type: String,
      required: false } },


  methods: {
    doAction() {
      this.showMessage = !this.showMessage;
      this[this.action]();
    },
    actionOne() {
      console.log('Action one called.');
    },
    actionTwo() {
      console.log('Action two called.');
    } } };




const routes = [
{ path: '/', name: 'home', components: { content: Home } },
{ path: "/one", name: 'one', components: { header: Header,
    content: contentOne }, props: { header: true, content: false } },
{ path: "/two", name: 'two', components: { header: Header, content: contentTwo }, props: { header: true, content: false } },
{ path: "/three", name: 'three', components: { header: Header, content: contentThree }, props: { header: true, content: false } },
{ path: "/four", name: 'four', components: { header: Header, content: contentFour }, props: { header: true, content: false } },
{ path: "/five", name: 'five', components: { header: Header, content: contentFive }, props: { header: true, content: false } }];


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for routes: routes
});

const app = new Vue({
  router }).
$mount("#app");
```

```css
#app {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px dashed lightgrey;
  padding: 2rem;
}

code {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.mainBody {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.mainNav{
  position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
background: tomato;
}

nav.mainNav > * {
  padding: 0 0.75rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav.mainNav > *:nth-last-child(n+2) {
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}


.router-link-exact-active.router-link-active {
    background: white;
}


.header {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  padding: 2rem;
}
.header h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.header h1.classOne {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.header .top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
button:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Tnagele SideBar</title>
  <!-- Favicon  -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="src/img/logo.png">
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="all.min.css">
  <!-- Bbootstrap 4.2.1 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body >
  <div class="wrapper">
  <!-- /.navbar -->
  <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
  <div class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-tnagele-teal  sidebar-no-expand">
     <!-- Brand Logo -->
     <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
     <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div id="app">
           <nav class="mainNav">
              <!-- Left navbar links -->
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="pushmenu" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
                 </li>
              </ul>
              <!-- use router-link component for navigation. -->
              <router-link :to="{ name: 'home'}">Home</router-link>
              <!-- specify the link by passing the `to` prop. -->
              <router-link :to="{ name: 'one', params: { color: 'red', title: 'Page One', description: 'Color and Title set. Default Text.' } }">One</router-link>
              <router-link :to="{ name: 'two', params: { color: 'green', customClasses: ['classOne'], title: 'Page Two', description: 'This is our new description.' } }">Two</router-link>
              <router-link :to="{ name: 'three', params: { color: 'purple', text: 'This is some random text.', description: 'Color and Text set. Default Title.' } }">Three</router-link>
              <router-link :to="{ name: 'four', params: { title: 'Page Four', action: 'actionOne', description: 'Only Title set. Action One.' } }">Four</router-link>
              <router-link :to="{ name: 'five', params: { action: 'actionTwo', description: 'All Defaults. Action Two.' } }">Five</router-link>
           </nav>
           <!-- route outlet -->
           <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
           <section class="mainBody">
              <router-view name="header"><button>asaaasas</button></router-view>
              <router-view name="content"></router-view>
           </section>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="sidebar-overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <!-- ./wrapper -->
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/2.5.3/vue-router.min.js"></script><script src="script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

He intentado representar lo que pones en la pregunta y lo tienes todo ok, si que es verdad que las cosas pueden ser mejores, pero no te apures, vas bien.

En cuanto a tu pregunta necesitas instanciar un componente para poder usarlos dentro de las vistas que defines como `contentOne` o similares.

Para esto tienes que usar algo como esto:

```js
Vue.component('new-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>new component</h1>
      <span>Counter: {{ counter }}</span>
      <br>
      <button @click="increment()">Increment</button>
    </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({ counter: 0 }),
  methods: {
    increment () { this.counter++ }
  }
});
```

Una vez hecho esto ya puedes usarlo dentro de las vistas que quieras, en este caso con el `contentOne` debería ser así:

```js
const contentOne = {
  template: `
    <section class="content">
      Content One 
      <new-component />
    </section>`
};
```

Te dejo el código con el ejemplo que te digo: https://jsbin.com/fifovax/edit?html,output

Aquí la documentación de componentes en vuejs: https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html